# Selecting a Path on Canvas which already has bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, mvvm

I'm still a little new to WPF so I apologize if there are one or two obvious concepts I'm missing.

I'm using WPF following the MVVM paradigm. My true problem is a little more complex so I will try to simplify. Say I have a few (in reality it's many) paths on a canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" Width="600" Height="300">
   <Path x:Name="Path1" Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" .../>
   <Path x:Name="Path2" Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" .../>
   <Path x:Name="Path3" Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" .../>
/>
```

And that style I'm using holds some bindings that keep all the Paths the same colors, like this:

```
<Style x:Key="PathStyle" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding FillColor, Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{Binding StrokeColor, Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

I can capture when the user clicks on one of the paths. When they do, I want to "override" the binding and change the colors of said path until the user clicks another one. I can manually set `Path.Stroke` when they click it, but I do not know how to "reactivate" the binding once I clear `SelectedPath` (therefore the path stays whatever color I set it to). I've tried obtaining the binding expression to force it to refresh, but the returns come out null (`selectedPath.GetBindingExpression(Path.StrokeProperty)`).

TL;DR: I want to make it so when the user clicks a path, it turns blue. When the click another path, I want it to go back to whatever color it's *supposed* to be, according to the binding in the style.

Any thoughts? Thanks for taking the time!

**Edit: Thank you for the solid suggestions - if I could push it a little more, what if there are nested canvases, but I still wanted to select only a single path? Such as:**

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas_Main" Width="600" Height="300">
   <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" Width="600" Height="300">
      <Path x:Name="Path1" Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" .../>
      <Path x:Name="Path2" Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" .../>
      <Path x:Name="Path3" Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" .../>
   />
   <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" Width="600" Height="300">
      <Path x:Name="Path1" Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" .../>
      <Path x:Name="Path2" Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" .../>
      <Path x:Name="Path3" Style="{StaticResource PathStyle}" .../>
   />
/>
```

Comment: Just a cosmetic advice: if you use `TargetType="Path"` in your style, there is no need to use `x:Key`

Comment: @Natxo that is not just a cosmetic change, it changes on what elements the style is applied, so you should be more careful with that.

Comment: @NovitchiS you are right, the style would be applied to all `Path` elements within the element in which `Resources` the style is defined. Which is what i assumed he wanted to do.

Comment: You probably could use a `TreeView` for the nesting, however the `Canvases` could not be the immediate children of their parent `Canvases` anymore. If you are using canvas placement properties you need to bind them in the `ItemContainerStyle`, because the item container will be the immediate children of the canvases/or if you have static items you can set them on manually created `TreeViewItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach also use a ListBox, but uses the ListBoxItem's `Background` and `BorderBrush` properties for the Path's `Fill` and `Stroke`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PathItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              StrokeThickness="3"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

It assumes that there is a view model like this:

```
public class PathItem
{
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PathItem> PathItems { get; set; }
}
```

---

In case the fill and stroke for both the selected and unslected state should also be provided by the view model, you would typically define them at the item level, e.g like shown below (which would also give you the option to have individual colors or brushes for each item.

```
public class PathItem
{
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
    public Brush UnselectedFill { get; set; }
    public Brush UnselectedStroke { get; set; }
    public Brush SelectedFill { get; set; }
    public Brush SelectedStroke { get; set; }
}
```

and then bind to those properties in the ItemContainerStyle:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding UnselectedFill}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding UnselectedStroke}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
                      Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      StrokeThickness="3"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SelectedFill}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding SelectedFill}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Binding to data right from the `ControlTemplate`, you so dirty :P

Comment: In the scope of this question, the ViewModel actually only has the `Fill` and `Stroke` colors, the paths come from the View, which was generated by Expression. The view in this case is something highly specific.

Comment: The Path (UI) elements are defined in the view, but the Path's geometry (its `Data` property) should be provided by the view model.

Comment: @H.B. Forgive my naivety, why is binding within a ControlTemplate undesired?

Comment: @AIng: `ControlTemplates` are supposed to be "closed", i.e. have no knowledge of the outside as they should function as a standalone visual representation of a control that is supposed to work on its own in all contexts. Here it's used in-place in the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` so that is more or less acceptable, but if someone were to try and refactor it into a generic resource, it would only work for very specific `DataContexts` due to the binding dependency. This is not that big of a deal but i would recommend avoiding it, it's not hard to do anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Something along the following:

1. Use a `ListBox`, it provides item selection.
2. Move your paths into the `ListBox` or bind the `ListBox.ItemsSource`.
3. Set the [`ListBox.ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) to a `Canvas`.
4. In the path style introduce a `DataTrigger` that triggers on `{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}`
5. Add a `Setter` to the trigger that changes the color of the selected path as desired.
6. (Add a `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` to override the `ListBoxItem.Template` if it looks weird by default.)

---

**Edit:** Was curious if it works as expected, so here's a standalone example:

```
<ListBox Height="300" Width="300">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Path>
        <Path.Data>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,25,25" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path>
        <Path.Data>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,25,25" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I keep learning that the ListBox in WPF is more powerful than I previously thought :) What if the canvas contains nested canvases? Does the TreeView come into play somewhere in that case?

Comment: An items control can only have one panel, so nested `Canvases` don't work. A `TreeView` simply contains items that are items controls themselves.